# How to re-scale one out of two "y-axis" to compare trends with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the dataframe `DailyVeDBA_P_atm` which summarizes per day the daily mean activity of an animal (`DailyVeDBA_P_atm$dailyVeDBA`) and the daily mean atmospheric pressure (`DailyVeDBA_P_atm$DailyP_atm`) through time (`DailyVeDBA_P_atm$Date`).

I'm trying to do a plot in which I can see the trends in activity compared with trends in Atmospheric Pressure. Here is the code and the plot I have got so far:

```
norm <- max(DailyVeDBA_P_atm$DailyP_atm,na.rm=TRUE)/max(DailyVeDBA_P_atm$dailyVeDBA,na.rm=TRUE)
p <- ggplot(DailyVeDBA_P_atm, aes(x = Date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = dailyVeDBA, colour = "Overall daily VeDBA")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = DailyP_atm/norm, colour = "Mean daily Atmospheric Pressure")) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "10 days", labels = date_format("%Y-%m-%d")) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*norm, name = "Mean daily Atmospheric Pressure")) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) +
  labs(title="Daily mean VeDBA and Mean daily Atmospheric Pressure through time",
       y = "Daily mean VeDBA",
       x = "Date",
       colour = "Parameter") +
  theme(legend.position = c(0.2, 0.1),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust=0.5, face="bold", margin = margin(0,0,12,0)),
        axis.title.y = element_text(margin = margin(t = 0, r = 12, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.title.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = 12, r = 0, b = 0, l = 0)),
        axis.text.x=element_text(angle=60, hjust=1))
```

[image]

My problem is that atmospheric pressure is so thin, I would like to change the scale of the right-y-axis to see with more detail the changes in the atmospheric pressure between days.

What should I add to my code?

Comment: `ggplot2` is designed against having multiple y-axes on one plot.  Why don't you just just make your dataframe "long", and then use `facet_grid(..., scale = 'free_y')`

Comment: Thanks @CurtF. To be honest, I like the look of the graphics in this way, and if I do it in the way you comment, I will need to go in detail on that. So, for the moment I would like to know a way of solving this without using another approach. However, I will take into account your advice seriously.

Comment: Furthermore, I would like to understand what is going on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match the range of one variable to the range of a different variable we can use the concept of [min-max normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_scaling). Suppose we have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:100,
                 y = rnorm(100) + 1:100,
                 z = rnorm(100, 10)*100 + (100:1) * 10)
```

Wherein `y` and `z` are measurements at some point `x`. To scale `z` to the range of `y`, we would need to compute a few things:

```
ymin <- min(df$y)
ymax <- max(df$y)
zmin <- min(df$z)
zmax <- max(df$z)
```

Now with this we can scale `z` to the range [0-1]:

> z' = (z - zmin) / (zmax - xmin)

And we can than scale the range [0-1] to the same range as `y` by using the next formula.

> z'' = z' * (ymax - ymin) + ymin

We can code these two subsequent transformations inside the `aes()` statement of a line:

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y),
            colour = "dodgerblue") +
  geom_line(aes(y = ((z - zmin)/(zmax - zmin)) * (ymax - ymin) + ymin),
            colour = "tomato")
```

And then reverse that transformation for the secundary axis (note that `.` is a placeholder for the values used to derive breaks and labels):

```
g + scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(
  ~ ((. - ymin) / (ymax - ymin)) * (zmax - zmin) + zmin, 
  name= "z")
)
```

And this has very reasonable ranges for both variables:

[image]

Alternatively, you can use a different feature scaling technique, which will work in similar ways. Demonstrated below is a Z-score/standardisation approach:

```
zmean <- mean(df$z)
zsd <- sd(df$z)
ymean <- mean(df$y)
ysd <- sd(df$y)

ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = y),
            colour = "dodgerblue") +
  geom_line(aes(y = ((z - zmean) / zsd) * ysd + ymean),
            colour = "tomato") +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(
    ~ ((. - ymean) / ysd) * zsd + zmean,
    name = "z"
  ))
```

[image]

However, I do agree with most of the comments that secondary axes are confusing, often unnecessary and should be avoided whenever convenience allows it.

Comment: Really nice answer. Thank you very much for your time teunbrand!!